# SQL Server 2012: Not able to copy data from Source to destination table using MERGE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two databases `TestDB_Source`, `TestDB_Dest`.

There are some tables and data in the `TestDB_Source` database.

`TestDB_Dest` contains all the tables that are present in the `TestDB_Source` database, but without any data.

There is a table `Addresses` which is present in both the databases.

Here I am trying to copy data for the table `Addresses` from `TestDB_Source` database to `TestDB_Dest` database.

I am using this SQL query:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION SYNC_ADDRESSDATA_TO_DEST
BEGIN TRY
    ----Target Table ----  TestDB_Source.dbo.Addresses  
    ----Source table ----- TestDB_Dest.dbo.Addresses
    MERGE [TestDB_Source].[dbo].[Addresses] AS TARGET
    USING (SELECT [ID], [City], [Country], [State], [ZipCode] 
           FROM [TestDB_Dest].[dbo].[Addresses]) AS SOURCE ON (TARGET.[ID] = SOURCE.[ID]) 

      WHEN MATCHED THEN 
         UPDATE SET TARGET.City = SOURCE.[City],
                    TARGET.State = SOURCE.[State], 
                    TARGET.Country = SOURCE.[Country],
                    TARGET.ZipCode = SOURCE.[ZipCode]

      --When no records are matched, insert the incoming records from source table to target table
      WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
         INSERT ([ID], [City], [Country], [State], [ZipCode]) 
         VALUES (SOURCE.[ID], SOURCE.[City], SOURCE.[Country], SOURCE.[State], SOURCE.[ZipCode]);

         SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION SYNC_ADDRESSDATA_TO_DEST
    RETURN
END CATCH

COMMIT TRANSACTION SYNC_ADDRESSDATA_TO_DEST
```

Since the `[TestDB_Dest].[dbo].[Addresses]` is empty then based on the not matched condition data should be copied from `TestDB_Source` to `TestDB_Dest`.

But here there are no rows inserted into the `[TestDB_Dest].[dbo].[Addresses]`

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: It's not working even if you'd run standalone query (w/o transaction)?

Comment: Is there anything that I am missing here. Can you please help me to point out.

Comment: Print something out in the `CATCH` block so you have some idea if the transaction is failing for some reason.

Comment: Like Gordon said, there might be a chance that your transaction is rolling changes back. I would say try running whole statement, that's in `TRY` block and see wether it fails or it succeeds.

Comment: I see the below mentioned error: Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Addresses' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Comment: So that's your issue. You need to enable identity insert on your table using this statement`SET IDENTITY [YourTable] ON;`. Don't forget to turn it off once insert is done.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently we've found your issue. Your destination table has identity column and if you want to explicitly insert into that field, you need to use `IDENTITY_INSERT`.

Your query silently fails because you've wrapped it up in a transaction and in `CATCH` block you just silently rollback transaction and do not throw any error message, that's why you thought that insert did not happen.

A simple example:

```
-- This query will execute even though it's erroneous and won't bring anything back
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT 1/0;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    END CATCH
END

-- This query will throw error message, because you can't divide anything by zero. THROW keyword does the job
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT 1/0;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        THROW;
    END CATCH
END
```

This query should work:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION SYNC_ADDRESSDATA_TO_DEST

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TestDB_Dest].[dbo].[Addresses] ON;

    ----Target Table ----  TestDB_Source.dbo.Addresses
    ----Source table ----- TestDB_Dest.dbo.Addresses
    MERGE [TestDB_Dest].[dbo].[Addresses] AS TARGET
    USING (
        SELECT [ID], [City], [Country], [State], [ZipCode]
        FROM [TestDB_Source].[dbo].[Addresses]
        ) AS SOURCE
        ON (TARGET.[ID] = SOURCE.[ID])
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
    SET TARGET.City = SOURCE.[City]
        , TARGET.STATE = SOURCE.[State]
        , TARGET.Country = SOURCE.[Country]
        , TARGET.ZipCode = SOURCE.[ZipCode]
    --When no records are matched, insert the incoming records from source table to target table
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ([ID], [City], [Country], [State], [ZipCode])
            VALUES (SOURCE.[ID], SOURCE.[City], SOURCE.[Country], SOURCE.[State], SOURCE.[ZipCode]);
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [TestDB_Dest].[dbo].[Addresses] OFF;

    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION SYNC_ADDRESSDATA_TO_DEST
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION SYNC_ADDRESSDATA_TO_DEST
    THROW;
END CATCH
```

On top of that, I think you've made a typo with `SOURCE` and `TARGET`. If you want to copy data from `[TestDB_Source]` to `[TestDB_Dest]`, then `[TestDB_Dest]` must be your target.

I've also amended the way you use transaction. That's the recommended way to use `TRANSACTION` in `TRY..CATCH` block.